# clause usage after preposition

Tags: prepositions, clauses, prepositional-phrases

I have seen some sentences similar to the following one in a way that -ing form of "be" is used.
The verb is "be" therein. I wonder what if it is another verb like drink, see, come, go etc. any verb.  followed by a preposition such as of, like,with, to, etc.
Could you provide some examples?
Does the topic has a special title?

- A tons of lies **with** the gobbledygook words **being** their words would
  ruin the relationship.
- “The "left join" command **with** the "albums table(schema)" **being** our
  left table would bring all the data.”
- I **being** a doctor **means** I can propose a cure for the sickness.
- It has nothing to do **with** you **being** a geek.

*Are they a kind of simplification?* For example,

- The "left join" command **with** the fact that the "albums
  table(schema)" **is** our left table would bring all the data.
- **The fact that** I'**m** a doctor means I can propose a cure for the sickness.
- It has nothing to do **with** the fact that you **are** a geek.

If it is kinda simplification, I don't understand how it is done and what it is.

Comment: Some of these examples are grammatical and some are not. For a number of reasons, none simple. There is no simple rule for when to use present participles and gerunds (both of which use the _-ing_ form of the verb), and you might want to simplify your question, since it's pretty chaotic right now.

Comment: @JohnLawler I will give the devil his due. I’m really troubled about this topic. If a full explanatory answer doesn’t come, I will start a bounty +50 points. It has been irking me a lot for a long time. I don’t want it anymore sir.